# Replacement for String.format(...Locale) in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

It looks like

```
fun String.format(
    locale: Locale,
    vararg args: Any?
): String
```

[is deprecated in Kotlin 1.4+](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/format.html). What is the replacement option? I see that format w/out Locale is still valid:

```
fun String.format(vararg args: Any?): String
```

Why would I no longer need to provide a `Locale`?

Comment: It's not deprecated for kotlin 1.4:  `Deprecated: Use Kotlin compiler 1.4 to avoid deprecation warning.` Use Kotlin 1.4 and Kotlin Plugin 1.4 for IDE

Comment: @IR42 It's weird that it says that but the definition in https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deprecated-since-kotlin/ seems to contradict it, and say exactly that it'll warn since 1.4 and say nothing for previous versions.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov they added the same functions but with new JVM names (`@JvmName()`) and the old ones are now marked as deprecated, but Kotlin 1.4 compiler  and Kotlin Plugin 1.4 will use the correct functions without `DeprecatedSinceKotlin` annotations

Answer (score 1):

This is the replacement in Kotlin 1.4:

```kotlin
@JvmName("formatNullable") fun String.format(
    locale: Locale?,
    vararg args: Any?
): String
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Kotlin*.

Make sure that you use the latest version of Kotlin plugin. If not, click *Install*.

Then *restart* the Android Studio.